# Force tableView reloadData from Modal Dismissal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When my application launches, a table view is present and uses the information in two arrays    `(countdowns and countdown_info)` to populate the cell title and description in the table view respectively.

A modal can be opened and used to create a new countdown. So far, it saves the data in a local file, closes, and then returns to the front controller, but the table is not updated with the new data.

How can I get the new information added to the table? The UITableView is named as *countdown_table

Thanks!

EDIT: The return code looks like this:

```
...Above Saves the File...

// The following generates a warning. ClockworkViewController is the main view controller.
//[[ClockworkViewController countdown_table] reloadData];

[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the newly added value to the array
2. Call `[tableview reloadData]` in your table view controller's **`viewWillAppear`** method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `[yourTableView reloadData]` function? You should call this either when the modal view is saved, or when the table view becomes active again. This will then check all of the tableView's methods for number of rows, number of sections, etc, and reload the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly call `[table reloadData]` when you dismiss the modal view

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Interface Builder to perform your presentations/dismissals, you can very easily reload the ParentVC's tableView from the ModalVC's `Exit Segue` (transitioning back to the ParentVC, of course).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourDismmssSegueID"]) {

        ParentVC *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        // perform any needed data manipulation here
        [vc.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```